# Windows Media Player - equivalent to car rewind/fast forward?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-media-player

In Windows Media Player (not center, specifically Win 7), is there a hot key or something that will let me skip forward or backward a few seconds or few minutes?  For this reason alone, I often use WinAmp or VLC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To rewind: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>b</kbd>

To fast-forward: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd>

press the combination once to begin, and again to stop.

Comment: my remote uses those shortcuts in its preconfiguration for Windows Media Player.  i don't use WMP so I haven't actually tested them.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that's the best they provide.  Not as impressive as CNTL-Right-Arrow in VLC.

Comment: here all all the shortcuts: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/knowledgecenter/keyboard_shortcuts/player11_winxp.mspx.  But it's disappointing what some of them really do.

Answer (score 0):

[WMP Keys](http://wmpkeys.sourceforge.net/) is a Windows Media Player plugin that adds global hotkey support.